# Page not being returned - CURL PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I am trying to use the oAuth Yahoo API. I have the Auth URL but my CURL is not returning anything. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

I want the login screen (assuming I have not already logged in) ..

```
$auth_url = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=qj94ktv';         

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$auth_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)        

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

THANK YOU

Comment: is your code like that or you forgot `';` at the end of URL ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake...but the actual code I am using has no syntax errors...I have updated my post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `curl_exec($ch);` is not passing to the browser. Also you don't follow location as it redirects, and `RETURNTRANSFER`

You need to assign it a variable or just dump it:

```
$auth_url = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=qj94ktv';         
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$auth_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Not working...I tried it out....But yahoo does give that error page if the oauth_token is wrong...

Comment: The link is proper coz when you paste the link in your browser it asks for login / permissions .

Comment: @MihaiLorga Thanks a lot for the help...It worked..But now when I enter the login credentials in yahoo, I don get the success conformation page...Can you point out the problem?

Comment: That's another question. And for a small answer, it's because it is making an AJAX call to `/config/login` and that does not exist on your server, it is remote.

Comment: I just need to send the login parameters to yahoo to get an oauth_access code...Is there a way in CURL to send the request (login) back and get the results? (I am sorry I am learning curl)

Comment: If you know any page which explains the process...I would be glad to go through it....

Comment: This is the best one [Yahoo OAuth Signing](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html)